# Using QGIS2Leaf plugin to export into leaflet but output results into browser crash?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, cad, qgis2leaf

Amateur GIS technician here, Just tried to export my converted cad cities pipelines into a shape files and then export it into leaflet using QGIS2Leaf but the browser crashes before the displaying the output.

Is it possible that what I'm trying to do is too much for the broswer? The size of the shape files is 110mb.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get rid of unnecessary attribute data or simplify the geometry for the webapp (see [How to get a Leaflet app with a big GeoJSON file to work on mobile devices?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77025/how-to-get-a-leaflet-app-with-a-big-geojson-file-to-work-on-mobile-devices) ) but the better choice would be to setup something like Geoserver and work with a wms-service.
By the way: how many features does your layer contain?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The CAD file does not contain attributes. It is primarily composed of lines. It is a drawing of the roads of the city so it's size is really big. Do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution to the problem. The CAD file was made of many line segments instead of one single line. We used SAGA's line simplification. Performance was significantly increased and the output displays properly. Zooming in however crashes the browser though.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: just seem the size of your data. I'm no expert on Leaflet at that scale. As said above, it could work with Geoserver, but I can't imagine that amount of JSON loading successfully.

Tom (qgis2leaf dev)

Comment: Thank you for helping. I uploaded the problematic cad file. Hopefully you can help me with a better solution.

http://goo.gl/w06XTi

Comment: Have seen in your answer below that simplification helped you. Have you also tried using the Coordinate precision value in the qgis2leaf dialog?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet, we transitioned into using Geonode to publish their layers, thank you though.